# How to plot a function defined with def?

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib, plot

I have a function

```
np.sin(x / 2.) * np.exp(x / 4.) + 6. * np.exp(-x / 4.)
```

and I can plot it by using following code:

```
x = np.arange(-5, 15, 2)
y = np.sin(x / 2.) * np.exp(x / 4.) + 6. * np.exp(-x / 4.)
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```

but if I define function plotting doesn't work:

```
rr = np.arange(-5, 15, 2)

def y(o): 
    return np.sin(o / 2.) * np.exp(o / 4.) + 6. * np.exp(-o / 4.)

def h(b):
    return int(y(b))

plt.plot(rr, h)
plt.show()
```

Why does it happen, and how could I change the code to plot the function?

Answer (score 10):

Try this instead:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

rr = np.arange(-5, 15, 2)

def y(o): 
    return np.sin(o / 2.) * np.exp(o / 4.) + 6. * np.exp(-o / 4.)

plt.plot(rr, y(rr).astype(np.int))
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

Answer from Hun holds good.

However, if you are very specific on using two function definitions, then try this:

```
def y(o): 
    return np.sin(o / 2.) * np.exp(o / 4.) + 6. * np.exp(-o / 4.)
def h(b):
    l = []
    for i in b:
        l.append(int(y(i)))
    return l
rr = np.arange(-5, 15, 2)
plt.plot(rr, h(rr))
plt.show()
```

To answer on why your code did not work, when you called the function 'h', you did not pass any parameter, hence this return the function definition or the memory location pointer of the function. Even if you had passed rr to h, h was not handled to convert it into an iterable.

Comment: If you really want to create an additional function to cast the data to `int`, you could simply replace the content of `h(b)` with `return y(b).astype(np.int)`. And if you really (for whatever reason) would like to keep a loop, its much faster if you first define the entire array as `l=np.zeros_like(b, dtype=np.int)`; for a large size of `b` creating an empty list and appending values is going to be much slower (but really, a loop here is unnecessary: use the power of `numpy` and its operations on arrays!)